# How to Convert string (culture != "en-US") to int C# 2005

Tags: string, keyboard, integer, cultureinfo

C# 2005, I have set the culture like below in Program.cs:

```
CultureInfo myCulture = new CultureInfo("bn-IN");// like "en-US", "ja-JP" etc...
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = myCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = myCulture;
Application.CurrentCulture = myCulture;
```

Then after opening the application I choose my keyboard, and hit keyboard 1 which puts my language version of 1. Now I want to convert it to integer so that I can perform addition, subtraction etc. So...

```
CultureInfo myCulture = Application.CurrentCulture;
myCulture.NumberFormat.DigitSubstitution = DigitShapes.NativeNational;
int i = Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.Text, myCulture.NumberFormat);// this line throws exception with message "Input string was not in a current format"
```

so how to convert a string in another culture(other than "en-US") to integer ?

Answer (score 2):

```
CultureInfo oldCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

type your value here with different culture and go back to your old culture

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oldCulture;
```